# I want to use PHP to take text from a textbox and add it to a text file

Tags: php, html, text-files

I have written a PHP script to run with HTML that takes the text entered into a textbox and place it in a text file, however, the code does not work and I cannot figure out why. I'm fairly new to PHP and it would be great if somebody could help :D

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Altering text files</title>
    </head>
<body>

<form name ="form1" method ="post" action = "">

<input type = "text" name = "string">
<input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Add text">

</form>

</body>
</html>
<?php

$file = "./lines.txt";
$write = $_POST['string']

file_put_contents($file , $write, FILE_APPEND);

?>
```

Comment: _the code does not work_ What doesn't work?

Comment: have you some error or something ?

Comment: Your form does not have an `action`.

Comment: It doesn't give me an error code, basically what happens is, I type into the text box, hit the "Add text" button but it doesn't add the text to the file "lines" in the folder

Comment: What can I use as the action? I'm not really too good at this

Comment: You forgot a semicolon (;) after "$_POST['string']"

Comment: @k97513 the action value is not needed if you want to post to the same page

Comment: @Sean I don't need an action value if I'm writing to a text file and the php is in the same html file?

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Altering text files</title>
    </head>
<body>

<form name ="form1" method ="post" action = "">

<input type = "text" name = "string">
<input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Add text">

</form>

</body>
</html>

<?php
if(isset($_POST))
{
    var_dump($_POST);
    echo 'foo!';
    /*$file = "./lines.txt";
    $write = $_POST['string'];

    file_put_contents($file , $write, FILE_APPEND);*/
}

?>
```

test it to see if something is printed

Comment: You copied the OPs typo of missing semicolon

Comment: where is missing a semicolon ?

Comment: your file get the extension php and you have a local server ? because it's work fine on my local

Comment: I ran the code that you suggested, I'm running the file on XAMPP loading the file as a HTML file

Comment: run it in your www folder on xampp in an index.php file, if it not works i really don't understand why, if it's work then remove var_dump, echo and commentary and it will works fine , good luck bro

Answer (score 0):

try to add semicolon after $_POST['string']
also try display errors to know if anything is going wrong

Comment: Adding a semicolon didn't work, what can I use to display errors? Nothing appears in my browser and I'm using Notepad++

Comment: update your php.ini file, change the value of 'display_errors' to 'On'. the location of the file dependence of the OS you use

Comment: you need to restart the server after making this change